# How to remove flick in intent of GoogleSignIn

Tags: android, google-signin

I have a flick I need to get rid of in a Spash activity where I call GoogleSignIn. I tried with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION but even with no result. This is my code,

```
private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {

    GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);
}

private void signIn() {
    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();

    Intent intent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_GET_TOKEN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_GET_TOKEN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:mimeType="*/*"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

style:

```
<style
    name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/back</item>
    <item name="android:previewImage">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.